# remoteAddr in Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I developed a grails app that recognizes the visitors country by using request.remoteAddr. I pushed the app to cloudfoundry and it works well but all the values for remoteAddr are all internal for cloudfoundry like 172.30.49.25 so my app doesn't recognize any country. I tried this address in http://www.ip2location.com/demo - same result.

So the question is: how can I get the actual IP address of the user in the Grails or Java application deployed in CloudFoudry?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to get this data from the `X-Cluster-Client-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request headers.

Something like:

```
request.getHeader("X-Cluster-Client-IP")
```